# Multiple calls to invalidate with different Rects

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, canvas, invalidation

I am extending my **root layout** so I can `drawBitmap` 4 arrows on it, one on each corner of the screen. These arrows will occassionally Blink at the same time.
[image]

I am doing this as an *optimization to avoid creating 4 additional Views*, so I guess it only makes sense if the areas are independently invalidated, because if the whole layout is invalidated & repainted, the performance loss will probably be bigger than the savings, as the root layout contains heavy stuff. I suppose is a good idea, but if anybody thinks it's not, please tell me why.

I tried to call invalidate(Rect) in the same function with each rect:

```
 public MyRootViewGroup extends FrameLayout {

     @Override
     public void draw (Canvas c) {
          super.draw(c); // Draw Viewgroup Children
          draw_arrows(); // Paint Arrows over children
          invalidate(rect_arrow_left);
          invalidate(rect_arrow_right);
          invalidate(rect_arrow_bottom);
          invalidate(rect_arrow_top);
     }
```

... but unfortunately it seems that only one region gets invalidated with this approach. I need to invalidate the whole layout to make it work.

**Question** If this FrameLayout contains other children (that get drawn in `super.draw()` ) but they don't change, will my call to `invalidate()` cause them all to be repainted? Or Android is somehow smart to detect that only the arrow region has changed despite triggering a full `invalidate`? Am I optimizing and saving 4 views, or am I breaking Android optimization pipeline?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your next Activity onCreate() method

```
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
ImageView imageView3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
ImageView imageView4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

Animation animBlank = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.blank);

imageView1.startAnimation(animBlank);
imageView2.startAnimation(animBlank);
imageView3.startAnimation(animBlank);
imageView4.startAnimation(animBlank);
```

Create an xml file which defines type of animation to perform. This file should be located under anim folder under res directory (res ⇒ anim ⇒ blink.xml). If you don’t have anim folder in your res directory create one.

put following code in blink.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="600"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
</set>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @Kush, but this is in fact what I'm trying to avoid. I'm manually drawing the arrows to save 4 views for performance :)